# How to create Contextual Modal Navigation in Svelte Kit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Is there some way in SvelteKit to make this kind of contextual modal navigation like Instagram?

You click on a photo on a profile page, showing a modal with a description etc., but you can still see the profile in the background. Also, the URL changes to the post's ID, and if you refresh, you are redirected to a page containing only this post.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, [Dynamic Routing in Sveltekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930303/sveltekit-how-do-i-do-slug-based-dynamic-routing).
I've used dynamic routes for Twitter-like URLs e.g. `www.twitter.com/elonmusk` but haven't on a modal. All the best!