# How to mark current URL with css class without using regex in this case?

Tags: javascript

Using SvelteKit (but is the same for each JS framework) I have a menu like this:

```
const menu = [
  { name: "players", url: "/players" },
  { name: "team", url: "/players/team" },
  { name: "player detail", url: "/players/[id]" }, // id can be a string here
  { name: "player's team coach detail", url: "/players/[id]/coach" }, // id can be a string here
  // and so on...
];
```

and I'm using it with a for loop using an `<a>` tag:

```html
<a href="{url}" class:current="{page.url.pathname.startsWith(url)}">
  {name}
</a>
```

As you can see the `class:current` part is wrong because it marks as current all these urls:

1. `/players` and
2. `/players/1` and so on player 2, 3...
3. `/players/team`, this is not correct for me

This is not what I need.

**I need a way to exclude the `/players/team` and the `coach` one.**

Is there a way without using regexes?

Comment: Can you print the values of `page.url.pathname` and `url` ?
I want to know if the possibility of `class:current="{url.startsWith(page.url.pathname)}"` works

Comment: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/web-standards#url-apis this is the page.url object.

Comment: It looks like it uses the same as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname

Comment: pls give a output screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
function checkUrl(url) {
  const [, p1, p2, p3] = page.url.pathname.split('/');
  
  if(url === '/players') {
    return p1 === 'players' && !p2;
  }

  if(url === '/players/team') {
    return p1 === 'players' && p2 === 'team';
  }

  if(url === '/players/[id]') {
    return p1 === 'players' && !!p2 && p2 !== 'team' && !p3;
  }

  if(url === '/players/[id]/coach') {
    return p1 === 'players' && !!p2 && p3
    === 'coach';
  }

  return false;
}

...

<a href="{url}" class:current="{checkUrl(url)}">
  {name}
</a>
```

Example:

```js
const menu = [
  { name: "players", url: "/players" },
  { name: "team", url: "/players/team" },
  { name: "player detail", url: "/players/[id]" },
  { name: "player's team coach detail", url: "/players/[id]/coach" }
  // and so on...
];

function checkUrl(url, pathname) {
  const [, p1, p2, p3] = pathname.split('/');
  
  if(url === '/players') {
    return p1 === 'players' && !p2;
  }

  if(url === '/players/team') {
    return p1 === 'players' && p2 === 'team';
  }

  if(url === '/players/[id]') {
    return p1 === 'players' && !!p2 && p2 !== 'team' && !p3;
  }
  
  if(url === '/players/[id]/coach') {
    return p1 === 'players' && !!p2 && p3
    === 'coach';
  }

  return false;
}

menu.forEach(obj => {
  console.log('url:', obj.url);
  console.log('/players', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players'));
  console.log('/players/', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/'));
  console.log('/players/1', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/1'));
  console.log('/players/str', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/str'));
  console.log('/players/team', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/team')); 
  console.log('/players/1/coach', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/1/coach'));

  console.log('-----------------------------------')
})
```

Here is a more generic way to do this:

```js
const menu = [
  { name: "players", url: "/players" },
  { name: "team", url: "/players/team" },
  { name: "player detail", url: "/players/[id]" },
  { name: "player's team coach detail", url: "/players/[id]/coach" }
  // and so on...
];

const excludedParams = {
    1: ['team'],
    2: ['coach']
};

function checkUrl(url, pathname) {
  const [, ...routeParams] = url.split('/');
  const [, ...params] = pathname.split('/');
  
  if(routeParams.at(-1) === '') {
    routeParams.pop();
  }
  
  if(params.at(-1) === '') {
    params.pop();
  }
  
  if(routeParams.length !== params.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  const check = routeParams.every((routeParam, index) => {
    const currParam = params[index];
    if(routeParam.startsWith('[') && routeParam.endsWith(']')) {
      let check = !!currParam;
      if(excludedParams?.[index]?.length) {
        check &= !excludedParams[index].includes(currParam);
      }
      return check;
    } else {
      return routeParam === currParam;
    }
  })
 
  return check;
}

menu.forEach(obj => {
  console.log('url:', obj.url);
  console.log('/players', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players'));
  console.log('/players/', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/'));
  console.log('/players/1', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/1'));
  console.log('/players/str', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/str'));
  console.log('/players/team', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/team')); 
  console.log('/players/str/coach', checkUrl(obj.url, '/players/1/coach'));
  console.log('-----------------------------------')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. And what if player's ID is not a number but a string instead?

Comment: Can you elaborate ? what do you expect if `url === '/players/team'` and `page.url.pathname === '/players/team'` ? and for `url === '/players/[id]'` and `page.url.pathname === '/players/team'`  ?

Comment: You used `isNaN` but I have also strings for player's ID like for example `/players/ABC`.

Comment: @FredHors Check my update, you can comment `&& P2 !== 'team'`  and `if(url === '/players/team') { ...`  depending on your requirements

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue because this code is specific for this issue and I need to be generic.

Comment: I can also have many levels menu, like: `/player/team/coach/shirt`.

Comment: Do you mean player**s** `/players/team/coach/shirt` ? check my update

Comment: I added a more generic way to check url params

Comment: Thank you very much but this not what I'm looking for. I need a way to do this in a generic way. players, team, coach are only an example.

Comment: So you need to add the full details of what you want to achieve. The second snippet is a generic method that covers what you've asked so far, you can test it with other cases and adapt it to your needs

Comment: maybe is's worth passing the `excludedParams` as an array to the `checkUrl` function?
I'm with @Fraction on this one. more details on what specifically needs to be generic would go a long way. Is the requirement that the `class:current` only be `true` on urls that contain the specific player ID? in which case you can grab the ID ie the `[slug]` via the load function as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930303/sveltekit-how-do-i-do-slug-based-dynamic-routing and https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing

Answer (score 0):

Use a built-in Svelte function `path` which returns the current route's path without the domain.

1st, store the current path in a variable using the svelte:window directive:

```
<svelte:window bind:currentPath="path" />
```

Then, inside for loop, use the `path` function to get the URL path of each menu item and compare it to the current path using the `===` operator. This will only add the `current` class to the menu item that matches the current path exactly, excluding the `/players/team` and coach URLs.

```
<a href="{url}" class:current="{path === url.path}">
  {name}
</a>
```

more precise and does not require the use of regex.

Comment: What if I have routes like: `/players`, `/players/team` and `/players/abc`?

Comment: @FredHors Using `===` will only add the `current` class to links with an exact match to the `url` in the menu. To exclude these URLs, you can use the `!==` operator along with an additional check for `/players` using the `startsWith()` method.

Comment: let me know what exactly to include/exclude, and i will update the answer with same

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```js
function isCurrentPage(pathname, url) {
  const segmentsInPath = pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean);
  const segmentsInUrl = url.split('/').filter(Boolean);  
  if (segmentsInPath.length > segmentsInUrl.length) return false;
  return pathname.startsWith(url);
}
```

```html
<a href="{url}" class:current="{isCurrentPage(page.url.pathname, url)}">
  {name}
</a>
```

This code doesn't make any assumptions about the number of segments there are in the route or even the prefix "players", since I assume you want it to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

By using regexes you can accomplish the same:

```js
const menu = [
  { name: "players", rurl: /\/players/, url: "/players" },
  { name: "team", rurl: /\/players\/team/, url: "/players/team" },
  { name: "player detail", rurl: /\/players\/[\d]/, url: "/players/[id]" },
  { name: "player's team coach detail", rurl: /\/players\/[\d]\/coach/,url: "/players/[id]/coach" }
  // and so on...
];
<a href="{url}" class:current="{page.url.pathname.match(rurl)}">
  {name}
</a>
```

What you are doing is performing a match of the URL regex version against the `page.url.pathname` that I assume it is a String object if not then you can use toString or parse it to string and do the match.

I got the [information about regexes from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You can search there for any other customization you need to do.